# How to render using renderajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii2, render, jquery-select2

I want to render a view create.php using renderAjax in the controller. I'm trying it right now but I'm not getting it to work. Because don't charge the js (select2, datatables, etc).

I tried all, but I can't loads them js. I tried using renderpartial, beginPage(), bodyPage(), load the jsfiles one by one, register de assets.

[Load with renderajax](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmZD5.png)

[Load with render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJxmw.png)

Controller - create

```
public function actionCreate($id)
{
    $alm = Almacen::find(['idAlm','nombre'])->where(['estado'=>1, 'idSuc'=>$id])->all();//lista Almacenes
    $model=new GuiaRemision();
     if ( $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
     }
    $prods=Producto::find()->select(['idPro','nombre'])->All();
    $model1 = new GuiaRemisionDetalle();
    if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax){
        return $this->renderAjax('create', array('alm' => $alm,'idSuc' => $id,'model' => $model, 'model1' => $model1, 'prods' => $prods)); 
    }           
}
```

View - Create.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\assets\AppAssetBack;
//AppAssetBack->jsOptions=['position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD];
AppAssetBack::register($this);
$this->beginPage();
$this->head();
$this->beginBody();
?>
<div class="general-index">
    <h2 class="text-center">TRASLADOS</h2>
    <article id="widget-grid" class="">
        <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" id="wid-id-1" data-widget-editbutton="false" 
        data-widget-custombutton="false" data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false">
            <header class="bg-color-blue">
                <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-plus"></i> </span><h2>REGISTRAR TRASLADO</h2>                
            </header>
            <div>
                <div class="jarviswidget-editbox"></div>
                <div class="widget-body ">
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => $model->formName(),'options' => ['class' => 'smart-form' ],'action'=> ['creartraslado']]);?>
                    <div id="bootstrap-wizard-1" class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <br>
                            <header>
                                <h3><strong>Paso 1 </strong> - Información de Guía de Remisión</h3>
                            </header>
                            <fieldset>
                        <section class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
                           <label>ALMACÉN:</label>
                           <label class="input">
                            <?= $form->field($model, 'destino',[
                                'template'=>"{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
                                ])->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($alm,'idAlm','nombre'),
                                ['prompt'=>'SELECCIONE UN ALMACÉN', 'style'=>'text-transform: uppercase; width:100%','class'=>'select2 input-sm']); 
                            ?>
                            </label>
                        </section>
                                 <section class="col col-sm-6 col-md-4" >
                                    <label>OBSERVACIÓN:</label>
                                   <label class="input">
                                    <?= $form->field($model, 'observacion',[
                                        'template'=>"  {input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
                                        ])->textarea(array('rows'=>3, 'class'=>'form-control', 'style'=>'resize: none;')) 
                                    ?>
                                    </label>
                                </section>
                            </fieldset>
                            <fieldset>
                        <section>
                                    <?php $model1->idGui=$model->idGui;?>
                                    <?= $form->field($model1, 'idGui',[
                                        'template'=>"{input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
                                        ])->textInput(['type'=>'hidden']);
                                    ?>
                        </section>

                        <section class="col col-sm-6 col-md-3" >
                                    <label>PRODUCTO:</label>
                                   <label class="input"><i class='icon-append fa fa-cubes'></i>
                                    <?= $form->field($model1, 'idPro',[
                                        'template'=>"  {input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
                                        ])->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map($prods,'idPro','nombre'),
                                        ['prompt'=>'SELECCIONE UNA OPCIÓN', 'style'=>'text-transform: uppercase; width:100%','class'=>'form-control select2']); 
                                    ?>
                                    </label>
                        </section>
                                <section class="col col-sm-6 col-md-2" >
                                <label>CANTIDAD:</label>
                                    <label class="input"><i class='icon-append fa fa-cubes'></i>
                                    <?= $form->field($model1, 'cantidad',[
                                        'template'=>"  {input}\n{hint}\n{error}"
                                        ])->textInput(array('placeholder'=>'CANTIDAD', 'type'=>'text', 'maxlength' => true)) 
                                    ?> 
                                    </label> 
                                </section>
                                <section class="col col-sm-6 col-md-2"><br/><?= Html::submitButton('AGREGAR', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm']);?></section>
                            </fieldset>
                            </div>


                            <header>
                                <h3><strong>Paso 2 </strong> - Lista Detalle</h3>
                            </header>

                                <table id='dt_basic' class='table table-bordered table-hover' >
                                    <thead><tr> <th class='text-center'>Producto</th><th class='text-center'>Cantidad</th><th class='text-center'>Precio</th><th class='text-center'>SubTotal</th><th  >Acción <a id='deleteLista' class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class='fa fa-trash' style='font-size: 12pt'></i></a> </th> </tr></thead>
                                    <tbody id="listaDetalle">
                                        <?php
                                        if(Yii::$app->session->has('lista')):
                                            foreach(Yii::$app->session->get('lista') as $lista):
                                                echo '<tr>';
                                                echo '<td>'.' ['.$lista['idPro'].'] '.$lista['idComDet'].'</td><td>'.$lista['cantidad'].' Unidades</td><td>S/. '. number_format($lista['precio'],2).'</td><td> S/. '.number_format($lista['subtotal'],2).'</td>
                                                     <td>'.Html::a("<span class='btn-label'><i class='fa fa-close'></i></span>", 
                                                        ['compra/deletelista'], 
                                                        ['class' => 'btn btn-labeled btn-warning btn-sm',
                                                        'onclick'=>"
                                                            $.ajax({
                                                                type     :'POST',
                                                                cache    : false,
                                                                data: {id: \$lista['idPro']},
                                                                url  : 'compra/deletelista',
                                                                success  : function(response) {
                                                                    $(\$form).trigger('reset');
                                                                    $('#listaDetalle').html(result);
                                                                }
                                                            });
                                                        return false"
                                                        ]).
                                                        '</td>';
                                                echo '</tr>';
                                            endforeach;
                                        endif;
                                        ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            <footer><?=Html::submitButton('REGISTRAR', ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])?></footer>
        <?php ActiveForm::end();?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             </div>
          </div>
    </article>
</div>

<?php 
$script= <<<JS
    $('form#{$model->formName()}').on('beforeSubmit', function(e){
        var \$form=$(this);
        $.post(
            \$form.attr("action"),
            \$form.serialize()
        )
        .done(function(result){

        }).fail(function(){
            console.log("Server error"); 
        });
        return false;
    });
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
$this->endBody();
$this->endPage(); 
?>
```

View - Index.php

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;
?>

<div class="panel-body" id="load_div">
  <div class="trabajador-index">
    <h2 class="text-center" >TRASLADO</h2>
    <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-sm bg-color-greenDark txt-color-white"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                <i class="fa fa-plusr"></i> NUEVO
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-sm bg-color-greenDark  dropdown-toggle"  data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-left">
            <?php foreach($suc as $s):?>
                <li>

                    <?= Html::a(mb_strtoupper($s->nombre,'utf-8'),NULL,['#','id' => $s->idSuc,'href' => '#', 'class'=>'nuevo']) ?>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <hr/>    

        <section id="widget-grid" class="">
        <div class="jarviswidget jarviswidget-color-darken" id="wid-id-0" data-widget-editbutton="false" 
                    data-widget-colorbutton="false" data-widget-deletebutton="false"
                    data-widget-togglebutton ="false" data-widget-fullscreenbutton ="false">
            <header class="bg-color-blue">
                    <span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i></span>
                    <h2>TRASLADOS DE ALMACÉN: &nbsp; <?= mb_strtoupper($nalm->nombre,'utf-8')?></h2>
                    <div class="widget-toolbar">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <button class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-xs bg-color-blue txt-color-white" style="border-color: #fff" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                SELECIONAR ALMACÉN <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
                                <?php foreach($alm as $a):?>
                                <li>
                                    <?= Html::a(mb_strtoupper($a->nombre,'utf-8'), ['index','id' => $a->idAlm]) ?>
                                </li>
                                <?php endforeach;?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </header>
                <div>
                    <div class="widget-body no-padding">
                        <table id="dt_basic" class="table table-bordered table-hover" >
                            <thead>     

                                <tr>
                                    <th class="text-center" data-class="expand"> ID</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" ><i class="txt-muted "></i> DESTINO</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" ><i class="txt-muted "></i> SERIE</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" ><i class="txt-muted "></i> DOCUMENTO</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" ><i class="txt-muted "></i> TIPO</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" data-hide="phone"><i class="txt-muted "></i> ESTADO</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" data-hide="phone, tablet,pc"><i class="txt-muted "></i> REGISTRO</th>
                                    <th class="text-center" ><i class="txt-muted "></i> ACCIÓN</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <?php foreach($data as $d): ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= $d['idGui']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= $d['nombre']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= $d['serie']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= $d['documento']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= $d['tipo']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?= ($d['estado'] == 1)?"<i class='fa fa-check txt-color-green'></i> Activo":
                                                                "<i class='fa fa-close txt-color-red'></i> Inactivo";?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" ><?php $date = new \DateTime($d['RF']); echo $date->format('d-m-Y').' por '.$d['RU']?></td>
                                    <td class="text-center" style="width: 120px">
                                        <?= Html::a("<span class='btn-label'><i class='fa fa-pencil-square-o'></i></span>", 
                                        ['update', 'id' => $d['idAlm']], 
                                        ['class' => 'btn btn-labeled btn-warning btn-sm']) ?>

                                        <?= Html::a("<span class='btn-label'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></span>", 
                                        ['delete', 'id' => $d['idAlm']], 
                                        ['class' => 'btn btn-labeled btn-danger btn-sm']) ?>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
<?php 
$script= <<<JS
$('a.nuevo').on('click', function(e) {
     $.ajax({
       url: '
JS;
$script.= Url::to(['traslado/create'])."',";
$script.= <<< JS
       dataType: 'html',
       data:{
           id: this.id
       },
       success: function(data) {
           $("#content").html(data);
       }
     });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($script);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

All renderAjax does is send a view file via your controller without use of the Layout attached to the controller, permitted via an Ajax request.

Use an Ajax request(with for example jQuery) to actually load the controller action into your Ajax or Ajax container.

Comment: Looking closer at your code you're not using a pjax or ajax container to reload/capture your new data. You're not sending an encoded json either. You SHOULD use renderAjax to literally fill an ajax or pjax container from an action or manually, from jquery.